# Get the frequency of the array with elements, according to the count of elements in the array

Tags: arrays, swift

Here I have the array of the elements. I would like get the array of elements from that, descending order based on the occurrence of the elements.

Ex: I Have array of elements `["a","b","a","g","a","c","g","g","b","a","b","c","b","c","f","a"]`

Expected Output is `["a", "b", "c", "g", "f"]`
- Because I have `a's-5, b's-4, c's-3, g's-3, f's-1`. (Showing in descending order, based on the count of repeated elements)

```
let x = ["1","2","3","1","1","2","3","3","3","3"]
let cnts = x.reduce(into: [:]) {
    counts, word in
    counts[word, default: 0] += 1
}
print(cnts) //["a": 5, "c": 3, "f": 1, "g": 3, "b": 4]
```

I am stuck after this, can anyone help me?

Comment: There are some inconsistencies. In the first array, "f" occurs only once, not four times. The output `["a": 5, "c": 3, "f": 1, "g": 3, "b": 4]` does not match the previously defined `let x = ["1","2","3","1","1","2","3","3","3","3"]`

Comment: When the items have the same number of occurences, does the order in expected output of these items have importance? ie: `["g", "f", "f", "g"]` => `[ "f", "g"]` or `["g", "f"]`?  If it has importance, based on order of appearance in the input? On alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a `O(n)` time complexity algorithm, you could use [*Counting sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (at the price of space complexity) :

```
let arr = ["a","b","a","g","a","c","g","g","b","a","b","c","b","c","f","a"]
```

Let's build the histogram of this array :

```
let histogram = arr.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
}
```

Then construct an array of arrays where the elements are put in the index that corresponds to the count mince their frequency :

```
var acc = Array(repeating: [String](), count: arr.count)
//Array indexes are 0-based
let lastIndex = arr.count - 2

let arrayOfArrays: [[String]] = histogram
    .reduce(into: acc) { accumulator, entry in
        accumulator[lastIndex - entry.value] += [entry.key]
}
```

And then flatten it :

```
let result = arrayOfArrays.flatMap { $0 }
```

And check the result :

```
print(result)
```

which yields :

> `["a", "b", "c", "g", "f"]`

Note that elements with the same frequency may appear in different orders between runs since a `Dictionary` isn't an ordered collection.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You can now *sort* the dictionary according to decreasing number of occurrences, and then extract the keys:

```
let result = cnts.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }).map { $0.key }
```

The full example:

```
let x = ["a","b","a","g","a","c","g","g","b","a","b","c","b","c","f","a"]
// 5 x "a", 4 x "b", 3 x "c", 1 x "f", 3 x "g"

let cnts = x.reduce(into: [:]) {
    counts, word in
    counts[word, default: 0] += 1
}
print(cnts) // ["g": 3, "c": 3, "b": 4, "f": 1, "a": 5]

let result = cnts.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }).map { $0.key }
print(result) // ["a", "b", "g", "c", "f"]
```

Comment: @Len_X: Thank you for the edit suggestion. But the shown output is correct. "f"  occurs only once in the given array. "c" and "g" both occur three times, so the order between those is unspecified.

Comment: Addendum: In Swift < 5,  sorting is `O(nlogn)` best case, `O(n^2)` worst case. In Swift 5, with TimSort, the best case would be `O(n)`, `O(nlogn)` worst case.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array by:

```
let arr = ["a","b","a","g","a","c","g","g","b","a","b","c","b","c","f","a"]
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

arr.forEach { counts[$0, default: 0] += 1 }

print(counts)
//["a": 5, "c": 3, "g": 3, "f": 1, "b": 4]
let sortedByValueDictionary = counts.sorted(by :{ $0.1 < $1.1 }).map { $0.key }
print(sortedByValueDictionary)
//["a", "b", "g", "c", "f"]
```

Comment: You sort the dictionary according to the *keys,* not according to the frequencies. The output is not correct because "g" occurs more often than "f".

Comment: Did you run your code? Now the output is `["f", "g", "c", "b", "a"]`, i.e. the opposite of the requested “descending order based on the occurrence of the elements.”

Comment: Do change the expression of `sortedByValueDictionary` to `counts.sorted(by :{ $0.1 > $1.1 }).map { $0.key }`